# Speed Up: query with a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I use the query below to select actors with minumum ages of movies.

```
SELECT production_cast.production_id, MIN(birthdate) FROM person
LEFT JOIN production_cast ON production_cast.person_id = person.id
WHERE birthdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY production_cast.production_id;
```

However IMDB dataset is very huge and it takes more than 300 seconds to complete. Without GROUP BY and MIN this query is working in 0.2 seconds:

```
SELECT production_cast.production_id FROM person
LEFT JOIN production_cast ON production_cast.person_id = person.id
WHERE birthdate IS NOT NULL;
```

Database engine is MyIsam. Mysql version is 5.7.2.  I tried to use these BTREE indexes on:

- production_cast.production_id
- person.birthdate
- person.birthdate and person.id
- production_cast.id and production_cast.production_id

*Brief output of explain is:*
**Person:** range, 
**Indexes:** idx_Person_id_birthdate, idx_Person_id_birthdate, 
**Extra:** Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

**Production_cast:** ref, 
**Indexes:** idx_Production_cast_person_id_production_id
**Extra:** Using index

person.id and production_cast.id are primary key indexes. production_cast.production_id is not an primary key but have an index. What can I do to increase the speed of this search query.

Comment: What does `explain select...` says for the above query ? Add that into the question.

Comment: Please show the layout of the tables.  For instance is `product_cast.id` a primary key?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Result for explain is:
**For person:** **key:** birthdate, **row:** 366741, **Extra:** 'Using index condition; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort'
**For production cast:** **possiblekeys**: PRIMARY, person_id **key**: person_id

**All ids is primary keys, birthdate have index**

Comment: You say the database is huge => there are many results => one simply cannot scroll all these results => why not use a paginator and limit the results ? PS : Try using subselect to get rid of the using filesort

Comment: I can't understand why anyone would purposefully choose MySQL when a perfectly good PostgreSQL exists

Comment: @Cosmin I changed something and now it is using again composite index for person(250 seconds to finish) but it is still using filesort( The main problem ). How can i prevent filesort usage with the same results?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some indexes to speed up the data retrieval.

On `production_cast`:

- `person_id`
- `id`

On `person`:

- `id`
- `birthdate`

This way, the database doesn't need to retrieve all data, just the data from the index. Also, the order of the index columns will speed up retrieval. You should also alias the `person.birth_date` column to the parse time goes down:

```
SELECT pc.id
,      MIN(p.birthdate)
FROM   person p
LEFT 
JOIN   production_cast pc
ON     pc.person_id = p.id
WHERE  p.birthdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP
BY     pc.id;
```

Comment: He definitely left out some important indexes

Comment: all indexes you mentioned exist.

Comment: @orcungumus: Did you copy them from me? How did you find those indexes? Are they *exactly* as above?

Comment: Actually, to test, i added all combinations at the start, but currently on **production_cast:** _person.id,  production_id, id_ and on **person:** _id,  birthdate_, and a composit index _(birthdate, id)_ exist. The problem is it uses composit index but it continues to make filesort

Comment: @PatrickHofman It uses both indexes (+1 for this) but it continues to make filesort. So it is still takes 190 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `LEFT JOIN` is not needed, unless you care about "person"s who are not in any production cast. That seems unlikely. So, your query is:

```
SELECT p.id, MIN(birthdate)
FROM person p JOIN
     production_cast pc
     ON pc.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.birthdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pc.id;
```

Second, if `production_cast.id` is a primary key and `person.id` is a primary key, then the query cannot produce duplicate values for a given `production_cast.id`. Hence, the `group by` is not necessary:

```
SELECT p.id, p.birthdate
FROM person p JOIN
     production_cast pc
     ON pc.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.birthdate IS NOT NULL;
```

I suspect that you have another table or another aggregation key in `production_cast`, but your query is not doing what you think it should be doing.